# Getting GitHub Repository Branch Name in .travis.yml

Tags: github, amazon-s3, travis-ci

So I have a Jekyll website being built by Travis-CI automatically after GitHub pushes and then published to Amazon S3.  It works great, but I would like to extend it a little further.  Basically I'd like to be able to detect which branch is being built and use that branch name to decide what S3 bucket to publish to, such as

```
branch dev
bucket myapp.{branchname} = myapp.dev

branch qa
bucket myapp.{branchname} = myapp.qa

branch prod
bucket myapp.{branchname} = myapp.prod
```

Is this possible?  And if so, how?

Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got it, you need to use $TRAVIS_BRANCH in the '.travis.yml' file, it will be replaced with the branch name.